# soapcpp2.exe not finds stlvector.h

Tags: visual-c++, gsoap

Trying to use gSOAP in windows with help of [codeproject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17958/CurrencyConvertor-How-to-Use-gSOAP-and-Webservices) .I run command

```
soapcpp2.exe -IC:\gsoap-2.8\import C:\polygon\CurrencyConv.h
```

And have error:

**`**Critical error: #import: Cannot open file "stlvector.h" for reading.**`**

Where is problem?